# What's the most appropriate site for COVID-19 statistics questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Regarding COVID-19, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) would be the appropriate place for *extrapolation* (forecasting) questions.

But for questions centred around the *interpretation* of COVID-19 data, which is the most appropriate site?

Some examples of 'interpretation' type questions:

- What counts as a COVID-19 death?
- Can those who contract COVID-19 a second time count twice in 'case' statistics?

Where (if anywhere) on Stack Exchange do such questions belong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) (formerly known as Health) has [quite a few questions about the COVID-19 pandemic](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19), including some that are about interpretation/application of statistics.

The usual caveats apply, e.g. search if your question hasn't already been asked, share your research, and check the [Help Center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting.